# Copy another worksheet along if formulas on the main worksheet refert to it Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Problem I have is, when I am saving my my worksheet as another workbook using code below I also need to copy additional worksheet only on one occasion when formulas on the worksheet I intend to save refer to the "Price List" worksheet, which I would need to also save along with the first worksheet. I hope it make sense. Also another small problem, when I save worksheet as a new workbook, I need that workbook to open imedietly, so that I can then continue to work with that workbook.

Here is my code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(LCase(ws.Name), "template") <> 0 Then
            cmbSheet.AddItem ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
'Continue to create your invoice and check for the archive folder existance
Private Sub ContinueButton_Click()

    If cmbSheet.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Invoice Template from the list to continue."
    ElseIf cmbSheet.Value <> 0 Then
        Dim response
        Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
        'Creating the directory only if it doesn't exist
        directoryPath = getDirectoryPath
        If Dir(directoryPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            response = MsgBox("The directory " & Settings.Range("_archiveDir").Value & " does not exist. Would you like to create it?", vbYesNo)
            If response = vbYes Then
                createDirectory directoryPath
                MsgBox "The folder has been created. " & directoryPath
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Else
                MsgBox "You need to create new folder " & Settings.Range("_archiveDir").Value & " to archive your invoices prior to creating them."
                GoTo THE_END
            End If
        End If
        If Dir(directoryPath, vbDirectory) <> directoryPath Then
            Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).Visible = True
        'Working in Excel 97-2007
            Dim FileExtStr As String
            Dim FileFormatNum As Long
            Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
            Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
            Dim Destwb As Workbook
            Dim TempFilePath As String
            Dim TempFileName As String
            Dim fName As String
            Dim sep As String
            sep = Application.PathSeparator

            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .EnableEvents = False
            End With

           'Copy the sheet to a new workbook

            Sourcewb.Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).Copy
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                        GoTo THE_END
                    Else
                        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 56
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            'Copy current colorscheme to the new Workbook
            For i = 1 To 56
                Destwb.Colors(i) = Sourcewb.Colors(i)
            Next i

            'If you want to change all cells in the worksheet to values, uncomment these lines.
            'With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
            'With Sourcewb.Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).UsedRange
            '    .Cells.Copy
            '    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            '    .Cells(1).Select
            'End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'Save the new workbook and close it
            Destwb.Sheets(1).Name = "Invoice"
            fName = Home.Range("_newInvoice").Value
            TempFilePath = directoryPath & sep
            TempFileName = fName

            With Destwb
                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With

            MsgBox "You can find the new file in " & TempFilePath & TempFileName
        End If
    End If

THE_END:

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    Unload Me


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, based on what you said you need to do two things:

- Copy a worksheet when formulas contain references to the "Price List" worksheet

  [image: Worksheet with formulas]
- Save the new worksheet as a new workbook and open immediately

**Here is code to paste in a module:**

```
        Sub IdentifyFormulaCellsAndCopy()

        '******** Find all cells that contain formulas and highlight any that refer to worksheet 'price list' **********

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range

        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        For Each rng In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

            If InStr(LCase(rng.Formula), "price list") <> 0 Then

                'Highlight cell if it contains formula
                rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

            End If

        Next rng

        '*******************************************************************************************************************


        '********* Save worksheet as new workbook, then activate and open immediately to begin work on it *******************

        'Hide alerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Dim FName As String
        Dim FPath As String
        Dim NewBook As Workbook

        FPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop"
        FName = "CopiedWorksheet " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"

        'Create a new workbook
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

        'Copy the 'template' worksheet into new workbook
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("template").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)

        'If file doesn't already exist, then save new workbook
        If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
        Else
            NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
        End If

        'Activate workbook that you just saved
        NewBook.Activate

        'Show Alerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        '**********************************************************************************************************************

    End Sub
```

**Notes:**

Depending on how you implement this code, you can add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to speed things up.

Also, this code assumes that you have worksheets with the names of *template* and *Price List*.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will give it a shot, can I somehow send you the spreadsheet so that you can take a look at it to adopt your answer to what I already have?

Comment: @AlexB Please first try to do it yourself and see what happens.  Then report back on what isn't working and we can troubleshoot it from there.

Comment: Something does not seem to be right, I am already creating a filepath in the original code, to save new workbook in my preferred location, do I need to do it again? Since I see that you have recreated filepath in your code. Also, it sould check for version of excel to save with correct extension, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AlexB Without actually being able to recreate the same environment that you're working with, it's difficult to go through your code.  If you already know your filepath, just tweak the code for that.  To check for version of Excel, use `Application.version`

Comment: I have just discovered another problem in my code, the 'Application.version' is actually not doing anything or something else is wrong in my code, because, when I am trying to save new worksheet in Excel 2013 it still saves it with .xls instead of .xlsx

Comment: @AlexB If you're modifying my code, go to the FName spot and change it to `FName = "CopiedWorksheet " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"`  Also, when debugging, go into your Sub Routine, then use F8 to 'step through' your code, you can see it line by line